# Circles disappear when maximizing, minimizing or resizing my JFrame.

Tags: java, swing, geometry, paintcomponent

This is my code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i+=100) {
                g.drawLine(i, 0, i, h);
            }
        }
    };
    panel1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            int x = arg0.getX();
            int y = arg0.getY();
            Graphics g = (Graphics) panel1.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
        }
    });
    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

What it does is when i click on frame a circle is drawn. after drawing some circles when i maximize or minimize or resize my frame the circles gets disappeared. how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override paintComponent() method of the panel. The circles should be added in a list. In the paintComponent() call super and then iterate through the list painting each circle.

Comment: I'm already overriding paintComponent of panel1 to draw default lines as `final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(){
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i+=100) {
     g.drawLine(i, 0, i, h);
    }
   }
  };` In panel1 declaration statement.

Comment: So even easier. Add the list of circles processing in the same method.

Comment: its done. i used map instead of list for storing circle positions and draw circles in paintcomponent and its working. Thnaks man.........

Comment: @mark: no one has mentioned *why* your error occurred, and you need to understand that the Graphics object that you obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component will be destroyed any time the component is repainted, destroying any drawing you've done with it. For this reason, in general you do not want to obtain your Graphics object in this way, but rather you want to use the Graphics object that the JVM passes into the paintComponent method. Note that this Graphics object is not permanent either, but that's OK since your drawing will be redone with a new Graphics object when this occurs